# When the call to invoke the adapter's procedure fails, the failure function does not execute

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I use the below code to call the adapter's procedure with its parameters. As you can see there is a success callback function and a failure callback function. When I build my application for the Windows 8 environment, the failure callback function does not execute if the app is not able to make the call. The app gets hanged and I need to kill the app.

The code works fine in Android and iOS environments. This is a Worklight 6.1 application.

```
MyFunc: function(cb, err, dataObject){                  
                var invocationData={
                    adapter :  ADAPTER_NAME,
                    procedure : PROCEDURE_NAME,                 
                    parameters : [dataObject["request"],dataObject["headers"]]
                };

                var options={
                        onSuccess:SuccessResponseHandler,
                        onFailure:FailureResponseHandler
                };

                function SuccessResponseHandler(response){

                    if(!isResponseValid(response)){

                        err(response);
                    }
                    else{
                        cb(response.invocationResult.array);    
                    }

                };

                function FailureResponseHandler(response){
                    alert("Error");
                };

                WL.Client.invokeProcedure (invocationData,options);
            },
```

Comment: Nothing in Visual Studio's Output view at the time of failure?

Comment: No. I get nothing. Its an unusual behavior only in windows8 build.

Comment: Can you recreate this in new app that only does adapter invocation (using the default HTTP adapter) with the same network conditions that trigger this behavior? (and also not in an anonymous function that has its own private functions)...

Comment: Ok. I'll do that and let you know if I get something.

Comment: Also elaborate: is the server down is just unreachable?

Comment: I have created a sample app and it is working fine. I mean the FAILURE function gets invoked, if the adapter doesn't connect to the service. I have used the same code as mentioned previously.

Comment: And if the server is down? Can you confirm When does this failure happens in both apps?

Comment: What I do is I create a Hotspot and switch off the internet at the time of login.

Comment: So with the sample app the failure is correctly invoked, but in your app it does not get invoked... that means that something else in your app is triggering this, that is not part of the code that you have supplied in the question.

Comment: I'm using object oriented javascript in which the syntax of writing a function is mentioned above.

Comment: That's not what I am asking. You say the same code is working in a new app but fails in yours. I am asking what else you are doing in your app that may trigger it. If you can provide a sample that can reproduce the failure in calling the onFailure callback, this will help. Otherwise I do not see where else to take this question.

Comment: Any news about the issue here?

Comment: Yes, I have analyzed the code of both apps. The first app( in which the failure function is not invoked) has callbacks and the other app( which is working) doesn't have callbacks. But, I'm still confused because the success function gets invoked even it has callbacks too.

Comment: I suggest to just alter the code.

Comment: Ok. Can you suggest what approach should I follow?

Comment: To the one that you have observed to be working.

Comment: I cannot do that because this app is an enterprise app and I cannot change the architecture.

Comment: What architecture. It's simply either calling private functions or external functions. I don't think it's such a major "architecture" change.

Answer (score 0):

Try two things:

1. move `function SuccessResponseHandler(response)` and `function FailureResponseHandler(response)` outside of `myFunc`.
2. make them anonymous functions

   ```
   var options = { 
       onSuccess: function(response) { ... },
       onFailure: function(response) { ... }
   }
   ```

Comment: Provide a project that can be debugged. If you can't provide yourself, provide a new one.

Comment: OK. I'll provide you a new project asap.